# Building WebRTC for iOS

Tags: ios, webrtc, chromium

Following the instructions given [here](https://webrtc.org/native-code/ios/) to build WebRTC for iOS. I did the gclient sync and download was successful. I was able to successfully check out the code, now I'm trying to configure the build. I'm using GN to configure as given in instructions, however I get this error: gn.py: Could not find gn executable at: ../Desktop/webRtc/buildtools/mac/gn

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you add `depot_tools` location to `PATH` environment variable?

Comment: @MaxPotapov yes i added depot_tools, its working now.. thanks